# Open images one by one, draw rectangle and then save in another folder

Tags: python, opencv

I want to open a folder where there are several images, in each image will be drawn a rectangle and saved with the same original name but in another folder

The problem is that images are created but overwritten, and I can not save with the same name automatically. I think I cannot define well the for loop.

```
import cv2
import glob
path = r'dir\*.tif'  # only .tif images
for file in glob.glob(path):
    im = pl_image(file, size= x)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0, 255, 0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x3,y1),(x4,y2),(0, 255, 0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x5,y1),(x6,y2),(0, 255, 0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x7,y1),(x8,y2),(0, 255, 0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x9,y1),(x10,y2),(0, 255, 0),2)
    cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.JPEG' %  , im) # this line I do not how to define, should be smt like this
```

This line works but it does not save with the original name

```
cv2.imwrite(r'other_dir\img.png',im)
```

Comment: Please rectify the indentation, and rerun the code before posting it here. Currently, there are syntax errors in this code too

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import glob
path = r'dir\*.tif'  # only .tif images
output_folder_path = "/home/output/"
for file in glob.glob(path):
    im = pl_image(file, size= x)
    output_file_name = output_folder_path+file.split("/")[-1]
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0, 255, 0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x3,y1),(x4,y2),(0, 255, 0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x5,y1),(x6,y2),(0, 255, 0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x7,y1),(x8,y2),(0, 255, 0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x9,y1),(x10,y2),(0, 255, 0),2)
    cv2.imwrite(output_file_name, im)
```

The Idea is to have a variable that stores the fully qualified file name for the output folder + existing filename

Comment: Thanks Thalish, I could do it. Just in case, it is necessary to add the . png or . jpg to the name: output_file_name+'.png'

Comment: Hey Daniel .. since you are splitting the input filename on '/' , you will get the same extension as your input file. Eg - a/b/image.png will give you image.png when you split on / and take the last element